# IIS Redirects to multiple domains and preserves the request file path and names

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm running IIS 8, Windows Server 2012.

My website has many sub-directories. An ideal url will look like:

**oldsite.com/subdir/subdir/pages/default.aspx**

I need to redirect (301) visitors to different domains and need to preserve the rest of the original url's file path (everything from the 2nd to the last slash "/").

I have a map of my redirects in an excel sheet, it looks like below:

**oldsite.com/subdirA/subdirB/pages/default.aspx -> newsiteA.com/subdirC/subdirD/pages/default.aspx**

So you see the whole thing has to change except the last part.

My web.config looks like this:

```
<rewrite>    
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="RedirectsCollectionParshareSites">           
      <add key="/subdirA/subdirB/" value="/subdirC/subdirD/" />
      <!--will have many of these add keys-->
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
<rules>
  <rule name="Rule1 for RedirectsCollectionParshareSites">
    <match url="^(.+)" />  
    <conditions>
      <add input="{RedirectsCollectionParshareSites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)" />           
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsiteA.com/{C:1}{C:3}" appendQueryString="true" />          
  </rule>


</rules>
```

My wish is to have many "add keys" - with the mapping from my excel sheet, and per new domain, I will have a new "rewriteMaps" section, with it's own "action".

My question is, is this the proper way of using this module? Any other suggestions?

Remember, I have about a thousand of these redirects to implement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to use the rewritemaps approach, but was able to do it by doing a rule per site:

```
<rule name="Rule:tes" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(\/subdirA)(\/subdirB)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsite.com/subdirC/subdirD/{C:3}" />
</rule>
```

It's harder for admins to update, but it works.